# What file is the package description in?

Tags: packaging

I am wanting to fix a typo in a package description, however I don't know how to access this information. I can see it using the apt-cache show  command, but where does the package manager actually get this info? I have scoured the source thinking it might pick it up from a config, or man but no dice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package description is taken from the file `debian/control` in the source package, which contains various metadata about the package including name, version and description. For example, if you wanted to access the description for the `coreutils` package, you could do:

```
$ apt-get source coreutils
```

to download the source package into the current directory (and unpack it), then:

```
$ vi coreutils-8.5/debian/control
```

to view and edit the package control file.